# Two versions of OneNote (2010 and 2016) I want 2010 to handle the onenote:/// urls. How can I achieve that?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

As indicated in the subject line I am running two OneNote versions.
Currently if I click on an onenote:/// url Onenote 2016 is started. How can I switch that to OneNote 2010?

Comment: You can modify the registry yourself or just install OneNote 2010 after you have installed OneNote 2016.

Comment: What key exactly ? I have tried this replace the content of this one HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\OneNote.URL.16-t\shell\Open\command  with the content of this one: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\OneNote.URL.14\Shell\Open\Command buit it did not work

Comment: The contents of both keys should be identical.  If anything you would delete the OneNote 2016 key, but I highly suspect, it would be created by OneNote 2016

Comment: It was not identical, I made it indentical and I resterted Explorer but that did not change anything